Why the rescource's caching time in Chrome is the result of Date plus max-age
I've found a curious question which confused me a lot. I have a HTML page that contains an image which is hosted on a CDN server. On first request (just a little before I uploaded the image), the response headers looks like this:

In 180 seconds, the response look like this:

After 180 seconds, I clear the browser cache and request again. The response code is 200 and everything looks normal:

But the next request (in 180 seconds) looks confused, and the response code is 304:

My question is: why does the browser think the cache is expired, does the expire time equal the response header Date plus Cache-Control: max-age?


Why does the browser think the cache is expired, does the expire time equal the response header Date plus Cache-Control: max-age?

That is approximately right.
RFC 9111 specifies how the freshness of the response is calculated.

The calculation to determine if a response is fresh is:
response_is_fresh = (freshness_lifetime > current_age)


The freshness lifetime in this case is max_age. The current age is more-or-less the current time minus the Date (see the specification for the detailed calculation). If you look at the Date of the "confusing" response you'll see clearly that the response is no longer fresh, hence the revalidation.
You might have been expecting a new Date header because you cleared the cache. But that doesn't affect the CDN, and you can see from the headers that the CDN returned a HIT. So you're still seeing a cached response, just one that came from the CDN rather than the browser cache.
